# How does flexigrid work with arrays?

Tags: jquery, arrays, flexigrid

I have an xml database and I would like to insert it into a flexigrid. Since the ajax request of flexigrids only reads files formatted in a certain way , and I cannot modify my database, I would like to know if making an external ajax request, and putting all the data in an associative array I can fill my flexigrid; if yes, how ? I tried to create a table and apply flexigrid as a method, but the grid I obtain doesn't work ( the columns aren't properly aligned, I can't sort them etc...) .
My associative array is as follows:

```
    MyArray[i] = {'Name': name, 'Address': address, 'Category': category}
```

Comment: What programming language are using?

Comment: Apart from using jQuery, I meant your server-side language?

Comment: @Anwar My server-side language is php...

Answer (score 0):

Flexigrid works on either Json format or XML format.
For both types, they have to be in a certain format.

The XML format has to be exactly like this:

```
<rows>
    <page>1</page>
    <total>2</total>
    <row id="reg1">
        <cell>reg1-cell1</cell>
        <cell>reg1-cell2</cell>
    </row>
    <row id="reg2">
        <cell>reg2-cell1</cell>
        <cell>reg2-cell2</cell>
    </row>
</rows>
```

In your server-side you have to parse the original XML file and re-produce this particular XML format.

Regarding the sorting issue:
After clicking one of the columns, flexigrid sends a few parameters to a defined **url** as below:

```
 $("#flex1").flexigrid({
                url: 'staff.php'
             });
```

It sends the sorted column, the order and more. In there server-side you'll grab the passed parameters to re-sort your rows.

Please check the [Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/wiki/TutorialPropertiesAndDocumentation) page for more information.

**Update:** Let's say that you have an array (**Customers**) that holds your data. In this case we will create an object which will hold that your data but in Json format as follow:

```
function formatCustomerResults(Customers){

     var rows = Array();

     for (i = 0; i < Customers.length; i++) {
         var item = Customers[i];

         rows.push({ cell: [item.CustomerId,
                            item.Name,
                            item.Phone,
                            item.Address]
     });
     }

     return {
         total: Customers.length,
         page: 1,
         rows: rows
     };
 }`
```

Then you'll call your function:

```
$("#FlexTable").flexAddData(formatCustomerResults(eval(data)));
```

Comment: As I already said in my first post, I know that flexigrid can read my database only if written in a certain manner and I can't parse my XML file: I just wanted to know if I could do the same thing but using arrays instead of XML.

Comment: My apologies for misunderstanding, I updated my answer and I hope it answers your question.

Comment: In an ajax request I built my array as you told me :
        rows.push({ cell: [id,
                    title,
                           name]});
   i++; 

and when the ajax request is finished I called this function, however it doesn't give any result nor errors...: 
$("#table").flexAddData({total: i,page: 1,rows: rows}); },

Comment: In case your data will be stored in an Javascript Array object why your doing Ajax request? there is no need to do an ajax request, just add pass it directly to the flexAddData(), don't forget the **eval**.
then use **$("#table").flexReload();**

Comment: I use the Ajax request to fetch the data I need; since you told me to build my array that way, I build it directly in the Ajax request. When it is finished, it calls the flexAddData() function with the following parameters {total: i,page: 1,rows: rows}. It should return the same result you told me... I used also the flexReload() function after flexAddData () ...

Comment: update : I tried to use the function exactly as you told me, adding flexReload() after but it doesn't work anyways, no result and no errors!!!!